# Querying Ontologies using SPARQL

Tags: java, jena

Can someone please explain how to query this ontology: https://www.w3.org/2005/Incubator/ssn/ssnx/ssn using SPARQL with Jena? My approach was to copy a schema from that available in this ontology into a file that's part of my Java project then query it.However,i think that this is wrong.Is it wrong?
Thank You